# How to Add LinkedIn SDK into existing project?

Tags: java, android, linkedin-api

They are providing android project zip file i don't know how to implement it somebody ask me to add as a module but i cant there are a lot of gradle issues.

I m using...

Android Studio 1.4
Gradle version 2.4
Android plugin version 1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Android 1.4.1
File -> New -> Import module -> Select unzipped LinkedIN folder

Comment: Every time after adding linked in  as module Android plugin stop working and gradle going to be restart..

Comment: So maybe try to:
copy linkedin-sdk to you main root project
add this: include ':app', ':linkedin-sdk' to settings.gradle
add this: compile project(':linkedin-sdk') to app build gradle
I am not sure if it will work

Comment: @MoosaBaloch did you have any luck?

Comment: Yes I did after some time

Comment: @Rzodkiewka how did you do it in the end?