# How To Import Linkedin SDK in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, linkedin-api

I usually import libraries with gradle but linkedin sdk don't seem to have that option available. So I downloaded their sdk as file from here:

[Linkedin SDK](https://developer.linkedin.com/downloads#androidsdk)

Anyway, the question is how do I actually import this in Android Studio?

Comment: Like a project module.

Comment: I never done that, which menus do I follow ?

Comment: have you checked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33146105/5151575) or [getting started](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk) ?

Comment: @user2741186 were you able to resolve this?

Comment: You can try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42785351/2557258